# What is causing this Duplicity "restart" to fail with "exit code '50'"?

Tags: 20.04, duplicity

This is part of the output from Duply, running on a 20.04 system.

```
 19 |Start duply v2.2, time is 2022-03-31 03:24:01.
 20 |Using profile '/etc/duply/system'.
 21 |Using installed duplicity version 0.8.12, python 3.8.10 (/usr/bin/python3), gpg 
     2.2.19 (Home: /root/.gnupg), awk 'GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, G
     NU MP 6.2.0)', grep 'grep (GNU grep) 3.4', bash '5.0.17(1)-relea
     se (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)'.
 22 |Autoset found secret key of first GPG_KEY entry '6DC41962' for signing.
 23 |Checking TEMP_DIR '/tmp' is a folder and writable (OK)
 24 |Test - Encrypt to '6DC41962' & Sign with '6DC41962' (OK)
 25 |Test - Decrypt (OK)
 26 |Test - Compare (OK)
 27 |Cleanup - Delete '/tmp/duply.2031592.1648697042_*'(OK)
 29 |--- Start running command BKP at 03:24:02.958 ---
 30 |Reading globbing filelist /etc/duply/system/exclude
 31 |Synchronizing remote metadata to local cache...
 32 |Deleting local /root/.cache/duplicity/duply_system/duplicity-full-signatures.202
     20322T032402Z.sigtar.gpg (not authoritative at backend).
 33 |Last full backup left a partial set, restarting.
 34 |Last full backup date: Tue Mar 22 03:24:02 2022
 35 |Reuse configured PASSPHRASE as SIGN_PASSPHRASE
 36 |RESTART: Volumes 1060 to 1060 failed to upload before termination.
 37 |         Restarting backup at volume 1060.
 38 |Restarting after volume 1059, file var/lib/autopostgresqlbackup/weekly/REDACTE
     D/redacted_week.11.2022-03-19_06h25m.sql.gz, block 298
 39 |Attempt 1 failed. BrokenPipeError: Broken pipe
 40 |Attempt 2 failed. BrokenPipeError: Broken pipe
 41 |Attempt 3 failed. BrokenPipeError: Broken pipe
 42 |Attempt 4 failed. BrokenPipeError: Broken pipe
 43 |Giving up after 5 attempts. BrokenPipeError: Broken pipe
 44 |04:57:25.120 Task 'BKP' failed with exit code '50'.
 45 |--- Finished state FAILED 'code 50' at 04:57:25.120 - Runtime 01:33:22.1
     61 ---
```

This has happened for several days in a row.

I've looked at that `.sql.gz` file and it seems fine. `file` command says it's exactly what I expect (gzip'd text), … I was thinking maybe the file or filesystem might be corrupted on that "block 298".

What does exit code '50' represent?
Is the BrokenPipeError from a pipe that's writing to the backend… or… ?
Any thoughts on this?

## Updates April 6

The backend "target" is an `s3+http://` URL. This is a Linode system that is running production services; the network connection is good (or I'd expect to have other issues, and monitoring alerts, etc.)

As suggested in an answer, I tried to force a cleanup. Which Duplicity dutifully did. I then started another backup... output is slightly different, but still broken pipes...

```
 19 |Start duply v2.2, time is 2022-04-06 03:24:01.
 20 |Using profile '/etc/duply/system'.
 21 |Using installed duplicity version 0.8.12, python 3.8.10 (/usr/bin/python3), gpg 
     2.2.19 (Home: /root/.gnupg), awk 'GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, G
     NU MP 6.2.0)', grep 'grep (GNU grep) 3.4', bash '5.0.17(1)-relea
     se (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)'.
 22 |Autoset found secret key of first GPG_KEY entry '6DC41962' for signing.
 23 |Checking TEMP_DIR '/tmp' is a folder and writable (OK)
 24 |Test - Encrypt to '6DC41962' & Sign with '6DC41962' (OK)
 25 |Test - Decrypt (OK)
 26 |Test - Compare (OK)
 27 |Cleanup - Delete '/tmp/duply.761614.1649215441_*'(OK)
 29 |--- Start running command BKP at 03:24:02.723 ---
 30 |Reading globbing filelist /etc/duply/system/exclude
 31 |Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.
 32 |Last full backup date: Sat Feb 19 03:24:03 2022
 33 |Last full backup is too old, forcing full backup
 34 |Reuse configured PASSPHRASE as SIGN_PASSPHRASE
 35 |Attempt 1 failed. BrokenPipeError: Broken pipe
 36 |Attempt 2 failed. BrokenPipeError: Broken pipe
 37 |Attempt 3 failed. BrokenPipeError: Broken pipe
 38 |Attempt 4 failed. BrokenPipeError: Broken pipe
 39 |Giving up after 5 attempts. BrokenPipeError: Broken pipe
 40 |16:21:20.829 Task 'BKP' failed with exit code '50'.
 41 |--- Finished state FAILED 'code 50' at 16:21:20.829 - Runtime 12:57:18.1
     06 ---
```

How do I figure out what it's doing when it gets the BrokenPipeError ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Circling back to close this loop… and the answer is . . .

**Update Boto from "boto" to "boto3".**

I eventually tried to setup a completely different, S3-compatible storage provider. But when I tried to use that new target, I got all sorts of weird errors—not config errors, but that-looks-like-broken-API errors.

Turns out my backup target was using schema "s3+http://" (a synonym for simply "s3://") and that selects the backend that uses "boto" [version 1]. All of which is deprecated; boto v1 and the Amazon S3 APIs that it uses.

I installed boto3 (apparently boto2 died on the vine?) via the `python3-boto3` package for my Ubuntu 20.04/Focal system…

Then changed my backend target to the method "boto3+s3://" and it works perfectly with no other changes to my configs.

Comment: Thanks! Changing the schema to boto3+s3 also fix `Error: UnsupportedBackendScheme: scheme not supported in url: s3://...`

Answer (score 1):

Experience has shown that `BrokenPipeError` can mean:

- a poor network connection
- a half-sleeping target USB device
- missing data

Looking at your logs, the issue appears to come from here:

```
 36 |RESTART: Volumes 1060 to 1060 failed to upload before termination.
 37 |         Restarting backup at volume 1060.
 38 |Restarting after volume 1059, file var/lib/autopostgresqlbackup/weekly/REDACTE
     D/redacted_week.11.2022-03-19_06h25m.sql.gz, block 298
```

There appear to be missing volumes from a previous backup, making it impossible for Duplicity complete the archive process. You *may* be able to resolve this by using `cleanup` with the `--force` option in Terminal:

```
duplicity cleanup --force /path/to/target
```

Comment: nice! This seems to have done the trick… I'm waiting for a backup to complete and then I'll circle back here.

Comment: Nice. Backups are crucial. Never leave home without one 

Comment: …unfortunately, not fixed. Any thoughts on how I can figure out exactly what Duplicity is doing when it now says (Q updated above)

Comment: …my problem remains unsolved. I need to figure out what exactly Duplicity is saying is the problem with that "error 50"  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`